# how to display the adaptive card in the bot using python language

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I have a python chatbot using the Microsoft Botframework and I'm using the  Adaptivecardbuilder library and I tried the sample in the docs but I couldn't display the card in the bot

```
async def on_message_activity(self, turn_context: TurnContext):
    card = AdaptiveCard()


    card.add(TextBlock(text="0.45 miles away", separator="true", spacing="large"))
    # add column set
    card.add(ColumnSet())

    # First column contents
    card.add(Column(width=2))
    card.add(TextBlock(text="BANK OF LINGFIELD BRANCH"))
    card.add(TextBlock(text="NE Branch", size="ExtraLarge", weight="Bolder"))
    card.add(TextBlock(text="4.2 stars", isSubtle=True, spacing="None"))
    card.add(TextBlock(text=f"Some review text for illustration", size="Small"))

    # Back up to column set
    card.up_one_level() 

    # Second column contents
    card.add(Column(width=1))
    card.add(Image(url="https://s17026.pcdn.co/wp- 
    content/uploads/sites/9/2018/08/Business-bank-account-e1534519443766.jpeg"))

    # Serialize to a json payload with a one-liner
    await card.to_json()
```

Comment: Here is the official sample for  how you could [`handle adaptive card in python bot`](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/python/07.using-adaptive-cards/bots/adaptive_cards_bot.py)

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the code in the bot to display the card? The snippet you've posted here only creates the card and serializes it to JSON. It doesn't actually tell the bot what to do with it, which is probably why you aren't seeing anything.

In the [Python Adaptive Cards Bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/96ba2b5448176e24f9c356e1b2c92c4fa5776e36/samples/python/07.using-adaptive-cards), you can see the code for [displaying an adaptive card in JSON format](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/96ba2b5448176e24f9c356e1b2c92c4fa5776e36/samples/python/07.using-adaptive-cards/bots/adaptive_cards_bot.py#L51). Instead of loading a random JSON file as the sample does, you would instead use the JSON you serialized from the card you created.

Keep in mind that the `adaptivecardbuilder` is a third-party library and will not have official support from Microsoft in the event of issues.